# Bash: fail on error during a section, then run another section regardless?

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to run a series of commands inside part of a script, and stop if any return a non-zero exit status. But also, **inside the same script**, I'd like a final command to always run, regardless of whether anything failed before.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
(
  # various commands go here
) &> /var/log/logfile
final_command_that_always_runs /var/log/logfile
```

Is this possible?

Perhaps I can 'set -e' for only one () section of a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parens invoke a subshell, so yes, you can set options within and they won't affect the parent shell.

**Edit from question asker**: I've marked this as the answer, but I thought it needed a demo - as the answer says, I needed to move the set -e inside the parens:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(
    set -e
    echo 'one'
    ls -la /var/notexist/two
    echo 'three'
) &> /var/tmp/logfile
cp /var/tmp/logfile /var/tmp/logfile2
```